# Saving new records with accepts_nested_attributes_for in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can i save more then one new related object in rails using accepts_nested_attributes_for? Currently it only allows me to save a single new record.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass it as an array of hashes such as

```
Model.new(:nested_model_attributes=>{[0]=>{:param=>value},[1]=>{:param=>value})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another example.
If i have admission model with has many siblings and i have single form where i am taking details about more than 1 sibling.
Then in controller i need write following code.

```
def new
    @admission = Admission.new()
    3.times { @admission.siblings.build }
end
```

Following will be your page code.

```
<%= form_for(@admission) do |f| %>
# fields of admission form
  <%= f.fields_for :siblings do |builder| %>
   # fields for siblings form
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

Following will be your model code.

```
class Admission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :siblings, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :siblings
end
```

Comment: What if I want to create arbitrary number of new objects with javascript?

Comment: Thanks. Part 2 has needed code. http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2